# $TERM specific NeoVim configuration

Tags: vimrc, neovim, terminal, linux, console

I spend half the time in a TTY (Linux console as in Ctrl+Alt+F2) and the other half in a X session. Unfortunately the color scheme I use for NeoVim in the graphical environment on `xterm` does not look good in the Linux console interface. Since the colors do not look the same in the TTY, some elements are not really readable or easy on the eyes with this scheme.

To get around the problem I use a script which tests the `$TERM` variable and adds the line for the color scheme in my `init.vim` before running NeoVim: if `$TERM` equals something else than `linux` the script adds the commands `colorscheme ...` to the config file. This way I start NeoVim with the default color scheme if the command `nvim` is issued in a Linux console; and with the specified color scheme if the command is issued in any other terminal emulator (`xterm` in my case).

I was wondering if there wasn't a more elegant way to go. I would like to implement this test in my `init.vim` without having to rely on a external program.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you share more details please? By tty do you mean a Linux console (as in Ctrl-Alt-F2 etc.)? What do you set $TERM to? What about color scheme, why do you feel you need a different one for tty vs. X? On X do you use a NeoVim GUI or do you just run NeoVim on a terminal like xterm, rxvt, GNOME Terminal, Konsole, etc.? If so, which?

Comment: Thank you @filbranden! I tried to clarify a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest thing to do is edit your vimrc/init.vim and test `$TERM`:

```
if $TERM ==# 'linux'
  " commands
  colorscheme ...
else
  " more commands
  colorscheme ...
endif
```

Comment: That's perfect! I thought Vim/NeoVim did not have access to the environment variables because I had troubles with user-defined variables. Looks like it is working with system-wide variables. I use `$TERM !=#` because I want a vanilla Vim in a TTY. Thanks!

Comment: @LoïcReynier as long as the variables are exported (in the environment), you’ll be able to access them (IIRC)